# Dropwizard : caching of prepared statements caching

Tags: java, prepared-statement, dropwizard

Using Dropwizard is it possible to do prepared statement caching?

it is written in the dropwizard documentation that it uses dbcp.

Comment: Your question is very thin and unclear.

Comment: Caching sounds like a non DW related problem. DW is just a collection of frameworks. You can use any database framework you wish and these will come with their own caching. e.g. look into hibernate. They support multiple cache startegies for all sorts of different use cases.